# AWS Glue Job Output File Name

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue ETL to migrate data from PostgreSQL to S3. The job I have set up reads the files in ok, the job runs successfully, there is a file added to the correct S3 bucket. The issue I have is that I cant rename the file - it is given a random name like part-0000-.csv. I'm new to Spark and Glue, help is appreciated.

So I tried to use the below code :

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from datetime import date

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "default", table_name = "default tbl", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("customer_type", "string", "customer_type", "string"), ("project_type", "string", "project_type", "string"), ("device_id", "string", "device_id", "string"),], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")



today = date.today()
d3 = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
print("d3 =", d3)

applymapping1=applymapping1.toDF()
repartitioned1 = applymapping1.repartition(1)

path="s3://{}/date/"+d3
repartitioned1.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 300).option('header', 'true').mode("overwrite").csv(path)


import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

s3_bucket='{}'
srcPrefix = '/date/20220128/'

new_name='TrackingReport-' + d3 

#getting all the content/file inside the bucket. 

print (s3_bucket)
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(s3_bucket)
for obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='date/'):
  print (obj.key)

response = client.list_objects(Bucket=s3_bucket,prefix=srcPrefix,)
names = response["Contents"]
print ("names")

#Find out the file which have part-000* in it's Key
particulars = [name['Key'] for name in names if 'part-000' in name['Key']]

print ("particulars")
#Find out the prefix of part-000*  
location = [particular.split('part-000')[0] for particular in particulars]

print ("location")

#Constrain - copy_object 
for key,particular in enumerate(particulars):
    client.copy_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, CopySource=s3_bucket + "/" + particular, Key=location[key]+"newfile")
    print ("for loop")
    client.delete_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=particular)


job.commit()
```

The error I got is -
Error :
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not set a name on write. Glue is using Spark under the hood which assigns those names to your files.

The only thing you can do is to rename it after writing.

Your job fails because you are not providing the AWS credentials for boto3. You could inject them via the [Glue Options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html), or by providing an extra file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you give any reference, how to rename it after writing. Really appreciate your time :)