# Why is AWS Glue job creating parition file names with 'unnamed' included in the file's name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

We are using an AWS Glue job to load and de-dupe data and we are making a change to no longer use the crawler to determine schema meta data - we are now explicitly defining it.

As a result, we are using AWS's recommended method 2 (see below)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/update-from-job.html

```
sink = glueContext.getSink(connection_type="s3",
                           path=tgt_path,
                           enableUpdateCatalog=True,
                           partitionKeys=partition_key)
sink.setFormat("glueparquet")
sink.setCatalogInfo(catalogDatabase=tgt_db, catalogTableName=tgt_table)
sink.writeFrame(last_transform)
```

We use this code in two separate jobs. The first job writes partition files with the following naming convention:

- run-timestamp-part-block-0-0-r-someNumber-snappy.parquet

Example: `run-1659269628417-part-block-0-0-r-00001-snappy.parquet`

However, the second job is writing the files with the following naming convention:

- run-unnamed-36-part-block-0-0-r-someNumber-snappy.parquet

Example: `run-unnamed-36-part-block-0-0-r-00001.snappy.parquet`

Does anyone know why `unnamed` is being applied to the file name as opposed to a `timestamp`? I have searched AWS's documentation, but have not had much success in getting an answer. The below link indicates that it is not possible to specify the target name on-the-fly - the file name can only be changed afterwards.

Note: the data in the `unnamed` file appears to be accurate.

[AWS Glue Job Output File Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951932/aws-glue-job-output-file-name)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @undetected Unfortunately, no. I just decided to live with it and move on. It's not breaking anything and the data in the files are correct. The only thing it is impacting is my poor OCD. lol

Comment: i haven’t it tried this yet but maybe passing in a job name as in input parameter and running job.init with that job name?

Comment: If you try it and get it to work then post it and I will test, confirm, and mark as answered. I am intrigued to know the answer. I have no idea what parameter to pass in. I am new to both AWS and Glue.